# Why isn't this easy join working? (mysql)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I have two tables, `classified` and `fordon`.

```
classified table:
classified_id (PK)
etc...

fordon table:
id (PK)
classified_id (FK)
```

I try to use this code:

```
SELECT * FROM classified, fordon WHERE classified.ad_id IN ('$solr_id_arr_imploded') AND classified.classified_id=fordon.classified_id
```

BTW, the array is a set of ad_id:s returned from solr, never mind that, that is not the problem here...

Then I use mysql_fetch_array in a while-loop to display all the results:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
```

but when I try to echo something which is inside the table `fordon`, then the index can't be found error appears. But whatever is inside the table `classified` works to echo!

Any ideas?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
   echo $row['type']; // This doesn't work, because the 'type' column is inside the 'fordon' table
   echo $row['headline']; // This does work because it's inside 'classified' table.
```

Comment: What does your code look like when you `echo` the results?

Comment: I meant, the actual while loop. :)

Comment: could I have the FK setup wrongly here? The FK is in the fordon table, maybe it should be other way around? (does it matter)

Comment: Try to change the query from `SELECT * FROM ...` to `SELECT fordon.type, classified.headline FROM ...` just to see if your query is set up correctly. Let me know if that returns the results, but I cannot tell if it has anything to do with where the foreign key resides.

Comment: it give a 'unknown column 'year' in field list'... but the headline works! hmmmm I have to get to work now, but I will have to try some more later... If you think of something please let me know... Thanks :)

Comment: Might be the values that were *imploded* (which is what I am guessing those are), you don't think they are the problem?

Comment: no I don't think it's the implode!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
SELECT * 
FROM classified c
INNER JOIN fordon f ON c.classified_id=f.classified_id
WHERE classified.ad_id IN ('$solr_id_arr_imploded');
```

Also, its generally not a good idea to use: `SELECT *`. Its better to either select only the elements you want or use the `*` in context of the table you are getting all from, e.g.

```
SELECT classified.* 
FROM classified c
INNER JOIN fordon f ON c.classified_id=f..classified_id
WHERE classified.ad_id IN ('$solr_id_arr_imploded');
```

When you do joins with a blanket `*` you get every field in all tables.

Comment: I believe that is what he wants to achieve.

Comment: understood, but what if you have classified.field_name and fordon.field_name. You now have an error because you are using SELECT *. Its generally good practice to just query specifically what you want, esp when you start joining tables. But do how you like, I am just suggesting ;)